# value missing on AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't find what the error is in an AJAX call.

I have a PHP file output:

```
[{"value":"123","name":"My Name"}]
```

and this output is correct. And my AJAX call returns `undefined` after success:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",                                       
    url: "correct_file_location.php",
    data: $(this.form).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (pk) {                                         
        alert(pk.value);                                                                            
        $("#label_id_name").text(pk.value);                         
    },
    error: function (){
        alert("error");                                         
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you get with `alert(pk[0].value)` ?

Comment: Use your browser devtools to check the answer to the request. Do you see some content in it ?

Comment: Is the php responding with that output as a string? It might be a JSON.parse issue. But yes, it's an array, so be sure to test pk[0].

Comment: @freedomn-m it works with [0]. Why not working without [0]?

Comment: Because its an array. [ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the result is an array of objects, you need to first get the object from the array, and then access the properties of that object.

```
pk[0].value
```

should work.

Comment: [0] results in retrieving the first element from the Array of object.
And once you have that object you can access properties of that object.

Comment: but i have same structure on diferent website and it works without

Comment: this thing should be independent of which language or server or website you are using. It would be great if you can post the JSON response you are using for other website so that we can evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

*It is showing undefined because you are getting an array of objects and not only object *

try what @freedomn-m suggested in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will be work.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",                                       
            url: "correct_file_location.php",
            //data: $(this.form).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (pk) {
            var data1 = JSON.parse(pk[0].value);

            console.log(data1);

        //  $("#label_id_name").text(pk.value);                         
                },
            error: function (){
            alert("error");                                         
            }
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will also work but your php response code must be in javascript object.
Please add below code in 'correct_file_location.php' and check with your ajax code.

'{"value":"123","name":"My Name"}';